# Как очистить html от тегов в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть html файл, как его очистить от html-тегов, используя стандартные модули python?

Comment: Зачем это нужно?

Comment: Можно использовать модуль re и регулярками заменить всё что не надо вам. точнее re.sub

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python

Comment: @Александр, https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2110496

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

TAG_PATTERN = re.compile(r'<[^>]+>')

def clear_html_tags(v):
    return TAG_RE.sub('', v)
```